# Python Script Exceuting and Interrupting

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python script that runs another script.

```
inp = int(input('Do you want to continue '))
flag=1
while inp>0:
    if flag==1:
        print ('Script should run for detection!')
        exec(open("obj_d.py").read())
        flag = 0

    else:
        print('Script should not run')
        continue
```

I wrote this script for *running and closing for a short time*. That means that when I give input 1 it should run this script and close automatically. But for my code it can't stop the running script.
So, how can I do that? (I don't want any change in `obj_d.py` file.) Is there any other way can you suggest doing that?

**obj_d.py:**

```
print('Here is your detection code ........................')
print('Started ...........')
while 1:
    print('object detector...........')
print('Finished ..............')
```

Comment: Why do you run `b.py` from `a.py`. Why dont you use python `import` and use b.py

Comment: @balderman Thanks for your response. If I import function, lots of library will need to import again as well as code can't terminated at any time that is the main problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to terminate `exec` from the calling script. If you want to stop it forcefully, you should use the `subprocess` module instead. Something like:

```
import time
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen("python obj_d.py", shell=True)
time.sleep(4)  # let it run for 4 seconds
p.kill()    # terminate the process
```